# how to implement payment gateway in windows phone 8.1/winRt application?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

how to implement the payment gateway in windows phone 8.1 application or windows 8.1 winRT applications .

Comment: Which payment gateway do you want to implement?

Comment: For PayPal try their [SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/windows-8-checkout-sdk/gs_win8xo/)

Comment: You question is overly broad and I have marked it for closing.

Comment: any payment gateway... payumoney?

Comment: what do you mean by overly broad?